What is stopping Einstein-Cartan theory (ECT) from being a bridge to a unifying theory?
I have recently read more about the Einstein-Cartan Theory and it seems to provide very interesting solutions (or hints thereof) that the General Relativity can't. Although it would not be the unifying theory by itself, it seems to offer a lot of insight of what such theory would provide. Would you agree? What do you think is stopping ECT from being used as a bridge to a unifying theory?
ECT already incorporates spin into the geometry of spacetime via torsion, which accounts for intrinsic angular momentum (spin) in matter. This could potentially be extended to the gauge fields of the fundamental forces.
One of the intriguing ideas arising from ECT is the potential link between spin-torsion interactions and dark matter. The spin of particles, as described by ECT, might offer insights into the dark matter interactions by explaining how such particles could couple to gravity and potentially other forces, leading to a unified framework for understanding dark matter and dark energy. In certain theoretical models, dark matter particles could exhibit spin properties influenced by torsion. If torsion were to couple with the electroweak or strong forces in certain limits, these particles could produce new phenomena that may help prove or better understand the fundamental forces.
A very interesting paper (https://dx.doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/aaf169) describes what the life of an Einstein-Cartan universe would look like. The Big Bounce refers to a cosmological model where the universe undergoes a contraction followed by a rebound, instead of starting with a singularity at the Big Bang. In this model, spin and torsion (as described in Einstein-Cartan theory) play a role in preventing singularities, offering an alternative to traditional Big Bang theory. Regarding wormholes, the article explores the possibility that these torsion-induced effects could lead to the formation of connections between different regions of spacetime, potentially allowing for wormhole-like structures, and the multi-verse.

I didn’t really see a question in the text, and the one in the title is very broad. Can you please focus the question substantially?

Hey, I've put it at the top, but just edited my text to put the question in bold. But also happy to take in any views/comments you have on ECT. Seems quite elegant but "forgotten" due to its mathematical complexity.

The questions in the title, and in bold, have only subjective, opinion-based answers. Please ask a question that has an objective answer.

If you used AI to generate the bullet points  — and they certainly sound like it — you’re expected to disclose that.

The answer claiming that "Einstein-Cartan theory is just a reformulation of general relativity" is definitely wrong. Einstein-Cartan theory is compatible with spinors/fermions, whereas general relativity per se is NOT compatible with spinors/fermions. Therefore, general relativity is already falsified by the sheer existence of spinors/fermions in our Universe. Saying general relativity is the correct theory of gravity is equivalent to saying you have a Zoology book which does NOT describe the majority of animals in the zoo.

Einstein-Cartan theory is just a riformulation of general relativity, with torsion.
What is stopping ECT to be a unified theory is the same thing that stops GR from being such a theory: ECT is incompatible* with quantum mechanics in the same way as GR is, so the classical nature of theory is the thing that prevents it to be a unified theory.
If you knew how to properly quantize such a theory, then the Quantum ECT would be a good step towards a unified theory. But at the moment is just another classical field theory like many others.

*They are not really incompatible, the fact is that there are no known ways to obtain a quantum theory of general relativity that match the experiments, up to now.

Aren’t string theories quantum theories with GR naturally emerging in their low-energy limit?

String theories do not match experimental data nor nature. So, no, they are not good quantizations of GR. They come close in some aspects but at the moment are simply not true models of reality.

What experiment falsifies string theory? The new particles that the LHC hoped to find don’t have to be at LHC energies. String theories match all GR experiments since they predict GR.

No it doesn't lol. String theory predicts negative $\Lambda$ and so that our universe is an AdS one, which clearly contradicts experiments. The only thing that string theory can accomplish in regard to matching reality is the fact that it has, between the countless predicted non-existing particles, the particles of the standard model + the graviton. And it doesn't even contain the standard model in all the vacua, most vacua simply do not contain the particles of the universe.

The status of string theory now, and maybe we hope that it will improve in the future, is the fact that is a mathematically well posed theory. But not a single string theory vacua is known to correspond to our universe. If the same framework will be successful in a dS universe maybe string theories will become more close to a real theory of GR, but as now it is nothing more than a pretty mathematical thing

I’m not a string theorist, and I wasn’t aware of the negative $\Lambda$ prediction. Thanks for educating me!

You're welcome, i study string theory and i think sometimes it is overhyped, it is a good theory but is far from a realistic one, a lot more work is needed before we can consider it a reliable model :)
